# How to read array object values in a single array

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to retrieve values of objects into a single array.

```js
var arrayOjObjects =  {
  "Fruits": ["Banana", "Apple"],
  "Vegetables": ["Carrot", "Chilli"],
  "Drinks": ["Coco", "Pepsi"]
}
```

```
Output = ["Banana", "Apple", "Carrot", "Chilli", "Coco", "Pepsi"]
```

Tried `Object.values(arrayOjObjects)` but it is giving multiple arrays. Any inputs on this?

Comment: Add [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), like:

```
Object.values(arrayOjObjects).flat()
```

> The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements
> concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of the `keys` and then reduce it to the desired result:

```js
var arrayOfObjects = {
  "Fruits": ["Banana", "Apple"],
  "Vegetables": ["Carrot", "Chilli"],
  "Drinks": ["Coco", "Pepsi"]
}

const output = Object.keys(arrayOfObjects).reduce((output, key) => {
  output.push(...arrayOfObjects[key]);
  return output;
}, [])

console.log(output)
//Output = ["Banana", "Apple", "Carrot", "Chilli", "Coco", "Pepsi"]
```